# Disable a hyperlink until condition satisfies in JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am working in JSP, I have a variable called available which varies, Also I have a href, if this available is 0 I want to disable the hyperlink, if greater than 0 enable it, I am not getting an idea how to do this, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is this available variable in jsp or javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSP

```
<% int available = 0; %>
```

In javascript:

```
<script language="javascript"> 

function access(){ 
   var available ="<%=available%>"; 
   if(available < 1){
       document.getElementById('testlink').disabled=true;
   }
   else{
       document.getElementById('testlink').disabled=false;
   }
} 

</script>
```